# Apply TimeSeries onto one or more Dataset Columns

Tags: dataset, query

I recently responded to a question on Wolfram Community. My solution works, but I believe it could be improved. I'm trying to apply a `TimeSeries` to one or more columns of a `Dataset`. The column headers are the year specifying the end of the time span of the columns. The start of each year is "Oct 1". For example, the data time span would be "Oct 1 1980" to "Sep 30 1981" for the column header "1981". There is a "date" column in "Month-Day" format, but for this problem it doesn't seem useful to use that because the year and fixed start day is specified already.

One can take advantage of the `TimeSeries` method of specifing a start time. The tricky part is that the start time is based on a column header ("Year"). See my code below.

My question is:

Is it possible to use only a `Dataset` query rather than use the method that I used which involves nesting the `Dataset` query within a `With` block and mapping that onto column keys? In other words, can I eliminate the `With` block?

The return value could be a `Dataset` rather than an `Association` as in my code.

The data is imported from a CSV file. Here is the solution that I used:

```
url = "https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/Internet/WCIS/AWS_PLOTS/basinCharts/\
POR/WTEQ/assocHUCut3/state_of_utah.csv";
ds1 = Import[url, "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]
```

```
yKeys = Keys[ds1[1]] // Normal // 
   StringCases[StringExpression @@ Table[DigitCharacter, 4]] // 
  Flatten

(* {"1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", \
"1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", \
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", \
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", \
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", \
"2021", "2022"} *)
```

```
assn1 = With[{y = #, yTS = ToString[ToExpression@# - 1]},
      y -> ds1[TimeSeries[#, {"Oct 1 " <> yTS}] &, y]
      ] & /@ yKeys // Association;

(* Extract one or more years worth of `TimeSeries`. *)

Lookup[assn1, {"1981", "2020", "2021", "2022"}]

(* {TimeSeries[...], TimeSeries[...], TimeSeries[...], TimeSeries[...] *)
```

Comment: does `tsds = ds1[
  KeyValueMap[Association[# -> TimeSeries[#2, {"Oct 1 " <> #}]] &]@*
   Transpose, yKeys]` give something close to what  you need?

Comment: ... or `ds1[Merge[TimeSeries], yKeys]`?

Comment: @kglr the expression for `tsds` is very close to what I'm looking for. I made one modification to make the start year correct: `tsds = ds1[
  KeyValueMap[
    Association[# -> 
       TimeSeries[#2, {"Oct 1 " <> 
          ToString[ToExpression[#] - 1]}]] &]@*Transpose, yKeys]`

Comment: @david: Does the URL link you provided above work properly? I tried to import the same dataset but it seems that the link is not working.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, yes I just copied from this post and tried it. Worked fine. Did you double check that you copied the whole link as posted?

Comment: @david: I noticed that if I run Mathematica as you typed in your question, it does not import the `CSV` file. However, if I choose the entire link and open the `Link`, then the `CSV` file is downloaded into my `Download` directory. I was assuming that running Mathematica as you showed in your question is sufficient to import the CSV file as a `Dataset[]`. Unfortunately, that does not work for me, and I do not know the reason why. Thank you for double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yearKeys = Select[SyntaxQ[#] && Internal`PossibleDateQ[{ToExpression@#, 1, 1}] &]@
   Normal[Keys[First @ ds1]];

timeSeries = ds1[Map[First] @* Merge[Identity] @*
   KeyValueMap[Association[# -> 
     TimeSeries[#2, {"Oct 1 " <> IntegerString[FromDigits @ # - 1]}]] &] @* Transpose, 
  yearKeys]
```

[image]

```
{timeSeries[{"1981", "2020", "2021", "2022"}], 
 Query[{"1981", "2020", "2021", "2022"}] @ timeSeries}
```

[image]

```
timeSeries[DateListPlot @* Map[List]@*{"1981", "1995", "2020", "2021", "2022"}]
```

[image]

```
timeSeries[{"1981", "1995", "2020", "2021", "2022"} /* Map[DateListPlot]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer. Can you make the slight change to the start date as I did in my comment above? That will account for the unconventional way the years start. I need to explore your use of Transpose. I'm still learning how to work efficiently with `Dataset` and `Query`. Thanks.

Comment: @david, updated with the change you suggested.